# Getting the element id and switching inside function with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox. When I click it I disabled a textarea. I have 4 groups of checkboxes and textareas.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" onchange="toggleDisabled_new_order_1(this.checked)" selected/>
<input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" onchange="toggleDisabled_new_order_2(this.checked)" selected/>
<input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" onchange="toggleDisabled_new_order_3(this.checked)" selected/>
<input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" onchange="toggleDisabled_new_order_4(this.checked)" selected/>
```

Textarea

```
 <textarea name="description" class="form-control m-input m-input--solid" id="toggleDisabled_new_order_1"disabled>DefaultText</textarea>
 <textarea name="description" class="form-control m-input m-input--solid" id="toggleDisabled_new_order_2"disabled>DefaultText</textarea>
 <textarea name="description" class="form-control m-input m-input--solid" id="toggleDisabled_new_order_3"disabled>DefaultText</textarea>
 <textarea name="description" class="form-control m-input m-input--solid" id="toggleDisabled_new_order_4"disabled>DefaultText</textarea>
```

I had to create functions for each

```
function toggleDisabled_new_order_1(_checked) {
    document.getElementById('element_id_1').disabled = _checked ? false : true;
}
function toggleDisabled_new_order_2(_checked) {
    document.getElementById('element_id_2').disabled = _checked ? false : true;
}
function toggleDisabled_new_order_3(_checked) {
    document.getElementById('element_id_3').disabled = _checked ? false : true;
}
function toggleDisabled_new_order_4(_checked) {
    document.getElementById('element_id_4').disabled = _checked ? false : true;
}
```

There should be an easier way to handle it wihout replicating the same code

Since I come from PHP, I though switch would make it, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: why can't you just pass in a number for each set and then based on that number, you can disable that set.

Comment: In the same page, I have 4* ( 1 checkbox,1 textarea ). The role of checkbox is to enable textarea ( default disabled ). When I click to any checbox others also gets enabled.

Comment: If you create a relationship between the checkbox's ID and the related text area, then they can all use the same listener. Say the checkbox ID is *cb_1* and textarea *tx_01*, then you can get the related textarea from the checkbox listener as `'tx_' + this.id.split('_')[1]`.

Comment: You can also do `...disabled = !_checked`.

Comment: @RobG in order to be able to use `this` you should call the function from the element context. We are not sure OP is doing so.

Comment: @UlysseBN—not sure what "call the function from the element context" means. There are numerous ways to set *this*, the OP need not even set it, they could pass *this* from the inline listener instead of *this.checked*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" onchange="toggleDisabled(this.checked,1)" 
<input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" onchange="toggleDisabled(this.checked,2)"
```

JS:

```
function toggleDisabled(_checked,num) {
        document.getElementById('element_id_'+num).disabled = _checked ? false : true;
}
```

It's basically just passing the set number as another param to your toggle function. Inside the function, you just concatenate that number when you do `the document.getElementById` so that it disabled only that particular number.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract an `id` parameter from your function in order to [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself):

```
function toggleDisabled_new_order_1(id, _checked) {
    document.getElementById('element_id_' + id).disabled = _checked ? false : true;
}
```

And as said in a comment by RobG, you can use `_checked` value rather than user a ternary operator:

```
document.getElementById('element_id_' + id).disabled = !_checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" id="input1" onchange="toggleDisabled_new_order_1(event,'idname')" selected/>

<textarea name="description" class="form-control m-input m-input--solid" id="idname">DefaultText</textarea>

function toggleDisabled_new_order_1(e,idname) {

    document.getElementById(idname).disabled = e.target.checked ? true : false;
}
```

You can pass Id name of textarea in the onChange function with an event. It will automatically disable the textarea if the checkbox is checked